# Context Root Not Found MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: debugging, deployment, server, ibm-mobilefirst, native

I am working with Ibm-MobileFirst 7.0.

1. I create project
2. I start server
3. I Build my App
4. I deploy my app
5. I run the web app corectly

When I want to run the native App, I see this in the navigator:

> "Context Root Not Found"

This is yhe link of my native execution.

Comment: Is all this happening within MFP Studio?
In your native application's wlclient.properties/plist, check for the context root

Comment: Please can you show me where is that file ? 
i've opened my native App and the file is not yet.

Comment: wlclient.properties should be there in 'assets' folder .Find in path native/app/src/main/assets/wlclient.properties

Comment: Thank you for all 
Yes now i have my wlclient.properties,how to use that for soving my bug ?

Comment: Your URL should look like this http://localhost:10080/worklightconsole/login.html

Comment: Thank you ,now i am going to my home,i wille reconstact you if i have a probleme whith this deployement ,Thank you you guide me so much